# The current Flask app is not registered with this 'SQLAlchemy' instance

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Recently, I have upgraded the Flask pacakage to 3.0.0 version but after upgrading now I am facing an error while committing any changes to the database through application.

**Error:**

```
RuntimeError: The current Flask app is not registered with this 'SQLAlchemy' instance. Did you forget to call 'init_app', or did you create multiple 'SQLAlchemy' instances?
```

I have upgraged the packages to the latest.

These are the three packages which I have upgarded to latest:

```
Flask==3.0.0
SQLAlchemy==2.0.23
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1
```

My **init**.py file:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object("config")
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

I tried to run my flask app and commit new data to the database through application but getting a Runtime error mentioned in issue discreption.

Expecting a fix of this issue.

Comment: So we are talking about a running application where your db operations worked and now you upgraded and this error is thrown?

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It looks like you might be creating 2 insances of sqlalchemy